# How to use catcode with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, catcodes

I have a need to use `` \catcode`\^^M=12 % `` in a Latex file for other purposes.

The file compiles OK with `lualatex` but gives an error in `tex4ht lua` mode.

Is there a way to make it work in tex4ht also? Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}
{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\begin{document}
{%
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\endlinechar=`\^^M %
test
}%
\end{document}
```

Now  `lualatex foo6.tex` compile OK. but  `make4ht --lua foo6.tex` does not:

```
make4ht --lua foo6.tex
Output dir:     
Compiler:   dvilualatex
Latex options:   -jobname=foo6 
tex4ht.sty :    xhtml,
tex4ht  
build_file  foo6.mk4
Cannot open config file foo6.mk4
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param correct_exit
setting param ext
Adding:     ext dvi
LaTeX call: dvilualatex  -jobname=foo6  '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,.a.b.c.\input foo6'
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo6.aux)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
^
l.9 \catcode`\^^
              M=12 %
?
```

This is TL 2016 on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`\^^M
```

is just a complicated way of writing 13, so if you do not want to disable tex4ht's use of `^` then you could use

```
\catcode13=12
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `\^^M` clashes with `^` which is redefined by `tex4ht` to produce superscripts. You can try to disable it using `no^` command line option:

```
make4ht -l foo6.tex no^
```

Comment: oh, I just found now all superscripts no long work? $x^3$ comes out as `x3` ? I did not realized this the price to pay. I am sorry but this will not work.  I have lots of math in the documents and can't lose superscripts ofcourse. Do you have any other magic solution to try? Thanks.,

Comment: @Nasser you can also change catcode of `^` to 7 before the `^^M` use. Or use David's solutions, which seems easiest